# How to restart python script after one second of going down using UPSTART?

Tags: 12.04, python, suspend, upstart

I am running my Python script using upstart feature of Ubuntu so that if for whatever reason my Python script dies or gets killed, it can be restarted automatically and everything is working fine -

So I decided to use `UPSTART` feature of Ubuntu to restart the Python script automatically.

After creating the `testing.conf` file like this in `/etc/init/testing.conf` -

```
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [016]

chdir /tekooz
exec python testing.py
respawn
```

I ran below sudo command to start it and I can see that process running using `ps ax` and my python script is also running fine.

```
root@bx13:/tekooz# sudo start testing
testing start/running, process 27794
```

Now if I kill the PID of the above process, then it get restarted automatically within few milliseconds or microseconds.

Is there any possibility of restarting my python script after 1 second if it has gone down or got killed? I don't want to restart immediately.

Comment: Consider putting the conf file in `~/.config/upstart/` so that you don't need `sudo`: you would use `initctl start testing` to start the script for example. (I am assuming that your conf file doesn't need root privileges.)

Comment: Ok. But my question is different than what you are suggesting. May be you are suggesting something else not related to my question.

Comment: That's why I commented and did not "answered" your question.

Comment: @edwin: Now I am realizing it's a bad idea to run with `sudo start testing`. In your example you told me I can place the file in `~/.config/upstart/` folder but I am not able to find this folder? Can you provide me the full path where I can put my file?

Comment: On Nautilus, go to your home folder and press Ctrl+H to show hidden files, you should see the `.config` directory. Inside `.config`, you need to create a folder named `upstart` (that is, if it doesn't exist just create it).

Comment: My ubuntu machines are all command line based. There is no UI as such. In this case, where do I search for `.config` directory?

Comment: Just run `mkdir -p ~/.config/upstart`. Then, when you want a new Upstart job: `cd ~/.config/upstart; nano new-job.conf`. The tilde (`~`) is short for `/home/your-username`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't really understand why you are using the root directory for this "test", and I don't really think that's what you want to do (you can end up breaking your system badly). Also, notice that if you are root (the `#` prompt) you don't need to "sudo".
Please consider editing the question to reflect what you are trying to achieve.

I will repeat, for the sake of completeness:

> Consider putting the conf file in `~/.config/upstart/` so that you don't need to sudo: you would use `initctl start testing` to start the script for example. (I am assuming that your conf file doesn't need root privileges.)

On reading the [cookbook](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#respawn), it says that the `pre-start`, `post-start`, and `post-stop` stanzas are rerun on a respawned job. This means you can do something like this:

```
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [016]

chdir /path/to/a/folder
respawn

exec python testing.py

post-stop script
  sleep 1
end script
```

This way there will be a 1 second delay before the script is respawned. (You can do the same with the `pre-start` stanza, this way the first invocation would have a 1 second delay, though.)